# How to deal with Staff of webapp <X> ?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

It sounds like staff/support/founders may come in as new users when they see their product mentioned. As a new user, there is not enough reputation to comment. So in some cases I see answers given with an email address to their support center.

How to deal with this without downvoting the answer?

Comment: Any idea why there is the 50 reputation limit in the first place?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment

Comment: Have you got an example?

Comment: @ChrisF http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/what-are-good-web-apps-for-funding-a-tech-startup/7466#7466

Comment: Definitely spam - how long to leave it to see if it gets updated?

Comment: Maybe a day ? The account is still unregistered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as they make it clear that they are the support centre and are offering a helpful answer as well as the link then leave it be.

If the answer is just a link then it should be down-voted or even flagged as spam. A comment about providing a more useful answer should posted first - to give them chance to rectify the post.